# How can I Compress My .show and .hide jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to jQuery and I know there has to be a faster and smaller amount of code to do this. So, what I have here are two divs. Div one will show a class in a different div. and Div two will hide this element once a user is done and clicks div two. I feel like my jquery code is way too long for this. Here's my JSFIDDLE . https://jsfiddle.net/g812sqry/

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <p id="one">Div One</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p id="two">Div Two</p>
    </div>
</div>


#one {
    width:60px;
    background-color:green;
    padding:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#two {
    width:60px;
    background-color:green;
    padding:10px;
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#one').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('#one').click(function () {
        $('#two').show();
    });
    $('#two').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('#two').click(function () {
        $('#one').show();
    });

});
```

Comment: I Believe I have to have at least 15 reputation points in order to accept an answer, right? I don't see any "accept" indicators anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `.toggle()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var elems = $("#one, #two");
    elems.click(function () {
        elems.toggle()
    });
})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g812sqry/4/

Comment: This is definitely the best and most compressed option. Thanks a bunch! Will be using this from here on.

Comment: Could you toggle three different divs if you made the variable 3 different div IDs?

Comment: @kenny _"Could you toggle three different divs if you made the variable 3 different div IDs?"_ Yes. That functionality is possible, by adjusting `js` at post. Note, however, that original Question specifically addresses two elements at _"what I have here are two divs."_ . Perhaps ask new Question , including specific requirements in text of Question ?

Answer (score 1):

You can club the click events for both the selectors.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#one, #two').click(function () {
        $('p').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g812sqry/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

This way better.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#one').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#two').show();
    });
    $('#two').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#one').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are already calling the `$('#divID').click()` function no need to call it a second time for both `#one` and `#two` DIV's

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#one').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#two').show();
    });
    $('#two').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#one').show();
    });
    });
```

```css
#one {

    width:60px;

    background-color:green;

    padding:10px;

    cursor:pointer;

}

#two {

    width:60px;

    background-color:green;

    padding:10px;

    display:none;

    cursor:pointer;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <p id="one">Div One</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p id="two">Div Two</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Eliminates the need on dependency on ids.

```
$('p').click(function () {
        $('p').toggle();       
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g812sqry/5/